# Background color of table cell

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

Which is the best way to change background color of cell. Here is what I try.

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
```

With the code above the background of the row is gray, but the text have background color.

I have tried the code below, but then the text is not visible.

```
 cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor clearColor];
 cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: is the text using different color?

Comment: @Piyush Patel what you suggest not work for me.

Comment: Set label's background to clear, label's text to a color of your preference (default text color is `[UIColor darkTextColor]`) and the cell's background to your preferred background. What is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

```
cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
```

when you clear textcolor then text font will be transparent so you can no see it